# Change Android version

Tags: android, eclipse

When I run Eclipse, I get *"The rendering target (Version 4.4) is still loading"* and I want the other (Version 1.6) I downloaded both. I have tried

> Windows > Android Virtual Device Manager,

and it shows me the target with *"Target Name"* is *"1.6"* and I tried

> Windows > Preference > Android

and I clicked on *"Android 1.6"* then *"Apply > OK"* but its still shows me that I'm using 4.4.

Also, in `activity_main.xml > Graphical Layout`, at the top middle window (about) there is Android green with a name *"Android version to use when rendering layout in Eclipse"* I want to change to 1.6 but its not there. Help :)

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project, select Preferences. Choose Android on the left, select the version you want to use

Comment: In "Properties", by choosing an Android 1.6, now its checked on Android 1.6 but it didnt work :(